# Build and Deploy Strategy for Java Project using Git

Tags: java, git, svn, deployment, build

So I am creating a personal Java project with two other friends and we are using git for source control.

And we want to just be able to commit changes to the repo which will be on a remote server(sort of staging environment) and then I want
to be able to just login to that staging env and run a build and deploy script that simply just compiles all the .java source code and generates and runs a jar file.

But my problem is that I am new with git(not my idea to use it, i used svn in the past) and after reading up on it there seems to be no concept of centralized or master repo.

So my question is is there any way to achieve what I want using git? How will the staging environment know where to build from if there is no master repo??

Thanks guys.

Comment: you can use a master branch [git strategy](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be very new to Git. You can [clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the repo to your staging server. When you login to the server, you can [pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) in the repo, which brings latest changes in the remote git repository to your stating server, and you can build&run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure a remote on your local git pointing to the staging server and push the changes each time you want to build.